# Event handling after HTML injection with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Vue is not registering event handler for HTML injected objects.  How do I do this manually or what is a better way to work around my problem?

Specifically, I send a query to my server to find a token in text and return the context (surrounding text) of that token as it exists in unstructured natural language.  The server also goes through the context and finds a list of those words that also happen to be in my token set.

When I render to my page I want all of these found tokens in the list to be clickable so that I can send the text of that token as a new search query.  The big problem I am having is my issue does not conform to a template.  The clickable text varies in number and positioning.

An example of what I am talking about is that my return may look like:

```
{
   "context": "When in the Course of human events, it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected",
   "chunks": ['human events', 'one people', 'political bands']
}
```

And the resulting output I am looking for is the sentence looks something like this in psuedocode:

```
When in the Course of <a @click='search("human events")'>human events</a>, it becomes necessary for <a @click='search("one people")'>one people</a> to dissolve the <a @click='search("political bands")'>political bands</a> which have connected
```

This is what I have tried so far though the click handler is not registered and the function never gets called:

```html
<v-flex xs10 v-html="addlink(context.context, context.chunks)"></v-flex>
```

and in my methods section:

```
addlink: function(words, matchterms){
                for(var index in matchterms){
                    var regquery = matchterms[index].replace(this.regEscape, '\\$&');
                    var query = matchterms[index];
                    var regEx = new RegExp(regquery, "ig");
                    words = words.replace(regEx, '<a href=\'#\' v-on:click.prevent=\'doSearch("'+ query +'")\'>' + query + '</a>');
                }
                return words;
            }
```

As I said, this does not work and I know why.  This is just showing that because of the nature of the problem is seems like regex is the correct solution but that gets me into a v-html injection situation.  Is there something I can do in Vue to register the event handlers or can some one tell me a better way to load this data so I keep my links inline with the sentence and make them functional as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could approach it:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <template v-for="segment in textSegments">
            <a v-if="segment.link" href="#" @click.prevent="search(segment.text)">
                {{ segment.text }}
            </a>
            <template v-else>
                {{ segment.text }}
            </template>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            "context": "When in the Course of human events, it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected",
            "chunks": ['human events', 'one people', 'political bands']
        }
    },

    computed: {
        textSegments () {
            const chunks = this.chunks

            // This needs escaping correctly
            const re = new RegExp('(' + chunks.join('|') + ')', 'gi')

            // The filter removes empty strings
            const segments = this.context.split(re).filter(text => text)

            return segments.map(segment => {
                return {
                    link: segment.match(re),
                    text: segment
                }
            })
        }
    },

    methods: {
        search (chunk) {
            console.log(chunk)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I've parsed the context text into an array of segments that can then be handled cleanly using Vue's template syntax.

I've used a single RegExp and `split`, which will not discard matches if you wrap them in a capture group, `(...)`.

Going back to your original example, `v-html` only supports native HTML, not Vue template syntax. So you can add events using `onclick` attributes but not `@click` or `v-on:click`. However, using `onclick` wouldn't provide easy access to your `search` method, which is scoped to your component.

Comment: I really like the way this was addressed.  I went about it a little differently in my implementation because of my code structure but this was definitely the inspiration for the solution I eventually put into place.  I decided to do a bit more data processing when I receive the data and kept the v-if/v-else in the page html (I am not setting up a true Vue app).  Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

I've already posted one answer but I've just realised that there's a totally different approach that might work depending on your circumstances.

You could use event delegation. So rather than putting click listeners on each `<a>` you could put a single listener on the wrapper element. Within the listener you could then check whether the clicked element was an `<a>` (using `event.target`) and act accordingly.